# Can I use JavaMail to send SMTP mail over a specific interface?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm able to look up network interfaces using java.net.NetworkInterface:

```
ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth4");
```

Is there a way to request that JavaMail send mail, using SMTP transport, via a specific interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the mail.smtp.localaddress property to the host name corresponding to a particular interface to bind to that interface.  Use NetworkInterface.getInetAddresses and look for an Inet4Address.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. The full set of available properties seems to be present in the com.sun.mail.smtp package documentation, https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question made any sense at all. When you're sending email via SMTP, you have to choose a SMTP host (either an IP address or a DNS alias name which will then be resolved to an IP address). Your OS will then pick which network interface to use based on the configured routing table.

Routing IP address to an interface doesn't sound like an application layer job at all.

Comment: In general I agree but I keep coming across cases with VPNs where people claim it's necessary.

Comment: This question make sense when you want present specific IP address in headers of email.