# how can i specify network interface when use SMTP send email in java, not http(s) connection

Tags: java, smtp, network-interface

my application is based on java, i'm using mail.jar and activation.jar to realize the feature of send email, now i need to specify network interface to send email in my application. any suggestions? thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is your code ? And are you not able to send Mail?

Comment: Please search for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006002/can-i-use-javamail-to-send-smtp-mail-over-a-specific-interface) before posting...

Comment: Big Thanks to @Eddie B, that what i'm needed. sorry for that i may searched not carefully enough~

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I can send Mail, what i needed is to specify a network interface to send mail. i've find solution with Eddie B's link. thanks~